# Update MVC partial view contains image handler

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, captcha, httphandler, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to build my captcha, and it's already done.

I use an HttpHandler where on the ProcessRequest I write the image as below.

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(byteImg));
```

Then I have a partial view where I have an image with src attribute to the handler, as well a reload button.
On the reload button I need to recreate a new captcha image, so I need to recall the handler, and of course, it will call the generate method to get a new image and write it in the response.

I try a lot of solutions with jQuery by reloading the div that contained the partial captcha view also remove and re-add the image and many other solutions.
Any help to reload the image without postback the entire page?.

Comment: You did not mention what problem you are having? Is it that image is generated but not updated on the UI? How did you set the `src` property of the image? Did you try to append a dynamic string in the src Url so that browsers do not cache the image? like this: `<img src='@Url.Action("YourController", "YourAction")?r=@(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString())' alt="Captcha Image" />`?

Comment: Sorry if my point is not clear, I have the image as below

Comment: Where is the image?